# Python multiprocessing execution time increases rapidly after 0.25*NUM_PROCESS

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I have a script which takes 15 (or other) dates in a row. For each date, split a dataframe `data` in `data_train`, which is before a `date`, and `data_val` which is equal to `date`. We then train a classifier and increment the `date` with one day i.e a rolling window.

Since the training takes some while, and is independent, I think multiprocessing would help out:

```py
import multiprocessing
import pandas as pd
import time
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

def train_classifier(data_train,data_val):
    t = time.perf_counter()
    model = LogisticRegression()
    model.fit(data_train["X"],data_train["y"])
    pred = model.predict(data_val["X"])
    acc = (pred==data_val["y"]).mean()
    
    print("Training time:",time.perf_counter()-t, flush =True)

    return acc 

def get_train_test_data(data):
    for date in pd.date_range("2021-01-01","2021-01-16",freq="D"):
        data_train = data.loc[data["date"]<date]
        data_val = data.loc[data["date"]==date]
        yield data_train,data_val

def run():
    data = load_data()
    N_PROCESSES = 16
    data_splitter = get_train_test_data(data)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes = N_PROCESSES) 
    outputs = pool.starmap(train_classifier,data_splitter)

if __name__=="__main__":
    run()
```

I have a 11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-11950H  CPU i.e 8 cores (16 logical), and the first 4 trainings takes around 140 sec each. Then the next training takes a while e.g 5000 sec and the 6th as well (then I stopped the program).

The data is quite evenly spread i.e there isn't a date which have a significant more amount of data which could explain the increased training time.
I thought that maybe it was an issue using more than 8 processes (since I have 8 physical cores), thus I lowered `NUM_PROCESSES` to 8. Now the same picture is showing but the increased training time is after 2 trainings now, which should conclude that it has nothing to do with the data, since we don't have 4 "fast trainings" now but only 2. Fun thing is that we get `0.25*NUM_PROCESS` of "fast trainings" but I don't know if that is just random.

Note, that I ran the script multiple times with 16 and 8 processors, and the same pattern occurs.

Have I introduced some kind of bottle-neck or why could this be the case?

Comment: most likely a bug in the code ... it's hard to tell what's wrong since all the functions in the above code will result in a lot of name errors anyway, but i can tell there are more bugs not shown.

Comment: I have updated the code and fixed some typo. It should now mirror my code correctly

Comment: are you running out of memory ? did you monitor your memory usage ? nothing in the code looks suspicious, so you should maybe use a profiler module, there are some that work with multiprocessing out there

Comment: My memory looks fine - not more than 46%